Is the shift map computable?
I was reading the paper "On computability of equilibrium states" and saw that the map they consider there has to be open, topologically exact, continuous and distance-expanding, but at the same time the map has to be computable. I know that the shift map satisfies these hypothesis (at least the unilateral), not the one about being computable, so I was wondering, is the shift map computable? To be honest, I don't know how to prove this, and I don't have any reference. The answer appear to be "yes", but yeah, I don't know. Does anybody know how to prove this or know any reference about it?
Thanks in advance!

Is the shift map the operation that takes an integer-indexed sequence and returns the sequence shifted by one position? Then likely this will reduce to adding $1$ to an integer, which is computable.

Yes it's computable. "However, the tape can be moved back and forth through the machine, this being one of the elementary operations of the machine." - Alan Turing, on his Turing Machine

That's interesting, I thought we had to use the definition of computable maps to prove it. SFT maps works the same way?
